# How to used Valr Websocket API with Arbitrage calculation bot?

Tags: python

We have created a bot for Arbitrage calculation in which our multiple users will log in and put valr API keys and details given a valr. we are connecting valr web socket and bot. but bot calculation and valr web socket using async await in Python but it is not working parallelly. so if you know how to run the calculations and bot parallel then please let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.